# While fetching contacts from google unexpected undefined index

Tags: php, google-api, google-contacts-api

when user allow permission & script start processing every data is shown perfectly but i get error

> PHP Notice:  Undefined index: gd$email in

here is my php code

```
if (!empty($contacts['feed']['entry']))
    {
foreach($contacts['feed']['entry'] as $contact)
    {

    // retrieve user photo

    if (isset($contact['link'][0]['href']))
        {
        $url = $contact['link'][0]['href'];
        $url = $url . '&access_token=' . urlencode($accesstoken);
        $curl = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
        $image = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        }


    if ($image === 'Photo not found')
        {

        // retrieve Name and email address

        $return[] = array(
            'name' => $contact['title']['$t'],
            'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
            'img_url' => '//cdn.twkcdn.com/profile/image/avatar.png?w=40&h=40&cf',
        );
        }
      else
        {

        // retrieve Name and email address

        $return[] = array(
            'name' => $contact['title']['$t'],
            'email' => $contact['gd$email'][0]['address'],
            'img_url' => $url,
        );
        }
    }

$google_contacts = $return; //returning all d
}
```

This is just example of half script & i don't know why fetching contacts from google take about 15 to 20 seconds everytime i visit this page

Comment: without a little more detail around which of googles api's your calling, it's going to be hard to guess at the response, I see 'gd$email' and I think google uses "gd:email" with a colon instead of a $.   If you're trying to drop a variable into the string, then you need to use double quotes, so the variable gets parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Google doesn't check that all entry has email address.

Add that immediatly after Foreach :

```
if (!array_key_exists('gd$email', $contact)){
    continue;
}
```